# How to access Model data from yii template

Tags: php, yii

I'm using aBound yii template for my app.
on the left side there is a div with information.
But in the template the info is static.
I want to access model data, and trying NOT to break MVC pattern.

1) where is the right place to create a Count function ? for example, how many active clients are in the database, is it in Client Model or in Client Controller ?

2) should it be static ?

Comment: Regardless of why you want that or how could it be implemented, as a general hint, this breaks MVC philosophy. Try to check, again, your code logic and data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The better approach is to make this function in Client Model, you might use [scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) for this.

2) This is static function, since it does not depend on an model instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget under /extensions directory. This is more portable within your application. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create#widget